# Hadoop Map Reduce CustomSplit/CustomRecordReader

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a huge text file and I wanted to split the file so that each chunk has 5 lines. I implemented my own GWASInputFormat and GWASRecordReader classes. However my question is, in the following code(which I copied from http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/), inside the initialize() method I have the following lines

```
FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
final Path file = split.getPath();
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
```

My question is,  Is the file already split by the time the initialize() method is called in my GWASRecordReader class? I thought that I was doing it(the split) in the GWASRecordReader class. Let me know if my thought process is right here.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader;

public class GWASRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {

private final int NLINESTOPROCESS = 5;
private LineReader in;
private LongWritable key;
private Text value = new Text();
private long start = 0;
private long pos = 0;
private long end = 0;
private int maxLineLength;

public void close() throws IOException {
    if(in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}

public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return key;
}

public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return value;
}

public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if(start == end) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    else {
        return Math.min(1.0f, (pos - start)/(float) (end - start));
    }
}

public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
    FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
    final Path file = split.getPath();
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    this.maxLineLength = conf.getInt("mapred.linerecordreader.maxlength",Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
    start = split.getStart();
    end = start + split.getLength();
    System.out.println("---------------SPLIT LENGTH---------------------" + split.getLength());
    boolean skipFirstLine = false;
    FSDataInputStream filein = fs.open(split.getPath());

    if(start != 0) {
        skipFirstLine = true;
        --start;
        filein.seek(start);
    }

    in = new LineReader(filein, conf);
    if(skipFirstLine) {
        start += in.readLine(new Text(),0,(int)Math.min((long)Integer.MAX_VALUE, end - start));
    }
    this.pos = start;
}

public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (key == null) {
        key = new LongWritable();
    }

    key.set(pos);

    if (value == null) {
        value = new Text();
    }
    value.clear();
    final Text endline = new Text("\n");
    int newSize = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<NLINESTOPROCESS;i++) {
        Text v = new Text();
        while( pos < end) {
            newSize = in.readLine(v ,maxLineLength, Math.max((int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end - pos), maxLineLength));
            value.append(v.getBytes(), 0, v.getLength());
            value.append(endline.getBytes(),0,endline.getLength());
            if(newSize == 0) {
                break;
            }
            pos += newSize;
            if(newSize < maxLineLength) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(newSize == 0) {
        key = null;
        value = null;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the input file will already be split. It basically goes like this:

`your input file(s) -> InputSplit -> RecordReader -> Mapper...`

Basically, `InputSplit` breaks the input into chunks, `RecordReader` breaks these chunks into key/value pairs. Note that `InputSplit` and `RecordReader` will be determined by the `InputFormat` you use. For example, `TextInputFormat` uses `FileSplit` to break apart the input, then `LineRecordReader` which processes each individual line with the position as the key, and the line itself as the value. 
So in your `GWASInputFormat` you'll need to look into what kind of `FileSplit` you use to see what it's passing to `GWASRecordReader`.

I would suggest looking into [`NLineInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) which "splits N lines of input as one split". It may be able to do exactly what you are trying to do yourself.

If you're trying to get 5 lines at a time as the value, and the line number of the first as a key, I would say you could do this with a customized `NLineInputFormat` and custom `LineRecordReader`. You don't need to worry as much about the input split I think, since the input format can split it into those 5 line chunks. Your `RecordReader` would be very similar to `LineRecordReader`, but instead of getting the byte position of the start of the chunk, you would get the line number. So the code would be almost identical except for that small change. So you could essentially copy and paste `NLineInputFormat` and `LineRecordReader` but then have the input format use your record reader that gets the line number. The code would be very similar.

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears some of the things. I want to track the line numbers of the input file and feed in the line number along with the input record as value to the mapper. So looks like I have to use my own Split, because the way in which I am doing now already splits the file. Can you please let me know what options do I have (I am thinking that I need to override the computeSplitSize() method). I searched all over the web but couldnt find a concrete answer if we can do it or not

Comment: @user1707141 I updated my answer to address that. Let me know if it makes sense or I need to explain better.

Comment: The fisrt part of this answer saved my life, I had a similar problem and I understood that my concern would be the RecordReader. I wanted to find records delimited by strings, so I went and found this awesome article. I know it's a late answer but it may be usefull to anyone who needs this: http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/